# Sitecore 10.3.1 - Could not find property 'clearroleswhensignin' on object of type: Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider

Tags: authentication, owin

In the process of upgrading to Sitecore XP 10.3.1 from 10.2 I got this error after deploying our code.

We use a custom identityprovider that has the  property set.

Answer (score 1):

Took a look in ILSpy and it looks like there's a typo in the property name. It's actually "clearroleswhen**sing**in"

Solution: Change your config patch to

```
<clearroleswhensingin>false</clearroleswhensingin>
```